# symfony 3.1 validation in entity getters

Tags: symfony

After a long search without a clear solution I need your advice:

I'm trying to do an example of this http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#getters but I don't understand how to do it.

I understated that I have to have a method in the entity that does the validation, isPasswordLegal() in the example. But when is it called?.

Is this documentation saying that I can make an annotation like:

```
@Assert\isPasswordLegal()
```

or

```
@Assert\isTrue(isPasswordLegal)
```

in the password attribute?.

I also read this http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/IsTrue.html but, like in the above mentioned link, the examples are the same without giving me a clue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Neither.** Let's have a look at the example.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @Assert\IsTrue(message = "The password must be valid")
 */
public function isPasswordLegal()
{
    // ... return true or false
}
```

The `@Assert\IsTrue()` statement is not referring to another method in the class. **The statement is referring to the method directly under the annotation.**

In this case, `function isPasswordLegal` is directly under the annotation, so `Assert\IsTrue()` will validate that `isPasswordLegal` returns `true`. If it doesn't return true an error will be triggered.

**Let's use this to complete the example.**

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @Assert\IsTrue(message = "The password must be valid!")
 */
public function isPasswordLegal()
{
    $password = $this->password;
    if($password !== "invalidPassword" && $password !== "anotherInvalidPassword"){
         return true;
    }
    else{
         return false;
    }
}
```

---

Edit: Answering a request for clarification in the comments:

An `Assert` **annotation applies to the method underneath it**. The method can validate anything you want. It is up to that method to check the password. The **name of the method is irrelevant**, it is just convention.

This **validation will occur when you flush the entity, or when the associated form is validated**.

Comment: Thanks galeaspablo. Yes, all this was clear and I agree with you, the validation could whatever you want. I tried all the examples I detailed in my first message and I get an exception, but magically when I leaved only the method it worked. Then, what I have to do if I want to validate with a getter assert an attribute called $surname?.  Perhaps just creating a method called isSurnameLegal()? why not isSurnameValid()?... this is the kind of things I often find missing in documentation.

Comment: @Carlos Regarding $surname, you could create another assert as `isSurnameLegal`. But you're right, **the method name can be whatever you want**. It's just not immediately clear in the documentation.

---- Please don't forget to accept my answer, if this solved your issue. ----

Also, I suggest to have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html - I prefer to do validation inside a single callback (multiple properties validated in one function).

Comment: Thanks galeaspablo. If the method could have any name and is not called  anywhere, how do you know it is being used?. That's the point I don't see clearly. Callbacks or Asserts, I have read that is a question of preferences. I will take a closer look to the callbacks to see the point. But first of all I would like to resolve this question.

Comment: You know the method is being used to validate, when it has an assert annotation above it.

Comment: I have to have some bad days because I don't understand the point. It's pretty clear that the annotation makes it an assert. But, why the annotation @assert\IsTrue(.... applies to the password attribute when in the annotation there is not any mention to it? Perhaps because the name of the method has the word "password" or perhaps in the method the attribute password is assigned to a variable or perhaps..... This is the question to answer.

Comment: The annotation applies to the method underneath it. The method can validate anything you want. It is up to that method to check the password. The naming is just convention.

Comment: Let me see if I understand the principle. If in an entity class there is a method, no matter which name it has, with an annotation @assert\IsTrue() is going to be run when the form associated is validated or when the entity class is flush(). Am I right?

Comment: Yup. That is how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, galeaspablo. If you create an answer with that comments I will accept it as the one who solves the issue.

Comment: I've added this under an edit at the bottom of my answer. :) Hope you're having fun with Symfony.